# How come the array of objects I'm creating is a set of nulls?

Tags: java, arrays, null

So I'm creating a class called dicegame. Here's the constructor.

```
public class dicegame {
```

private static int a, b, winner;

```
public dicegame() 
{
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    winner = 2;
}
```

And now in the main, I'm creating an array of this object (I called it spaghetti for fun).

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    dicegame[] spaghetti = new dicegame[10];
spaghetti[1].roll();


}
```

But when I try to do anything to an element in the array, I'm getting the NullPointerException. When I tried to print one of the elements, I got a null.

Answer (score 1):

You created an array, but you have to assign something (e.g. new dicegame()) to each element of the array.

My Java is slightly rusty, but this should be close:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    spaghetti[i] = new dicegame();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `spaghetti[1]=new dicegame()` before you call roll() on it.
Right now you are allocating an array,but don't. Place any objects in this array, so by default java makes them null.

Answer (score 1):

```
new dicegame[10]
```

just creates an array with 10 empty elements.  You still have to put a dicegame in each element:

```
spaghetti[0] = new dicegame();
spaghetti[1] = new dicegame();
spaghetti[2] = new dicegame();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

1.you have just declared the array variable but not created the object yet. try this

2.you should start index with zero not with one.

```
dicegame[] spaghetti = new dicegame[10]; // created array variable of dicegame

for (int i = 0; i < spaghetti.length; i++) {
    spaghetti[i] = new dicegame(); // creating object an assgning to element of spaghetti
    spaghetti[i].roll(); // calling roll method.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,you should create object for every spaghetti input of yours.
You can start with whatever value you want. Just be sure that the size of array is matched accordingly so that you won't get ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception.

So,if you wanted to start with 1 and have 10 objects of the class dicegame,you will have to assign the size of the array as 11(since it starts from zero).

your main function should be like :

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
dicegame[] spaghetti = new dicegame[11];
//the below two lines create object for every spaghetti item
for(int i=1;i<=11;i++)
spaghetti[i]=new dicegame();

//and now if you want to call the function roll for the first element,just call it
spaghetti[1].roll;
}
```